# Join, join in or take part in a talent show?

Tags: collocation

Which of the following has the correct collocation? Please explain the differences. Thank you very much.

A. Tom has joined a talent show.
B. Tom has joined in a talent show.
C. Tom has taken part in a talent show.

Comment: How does a user tell if you understand the meanings of each sentence? Have you looked up the different meanings of the verbs: **join** and **take part**?

Answer (score 1):

A talent show is a competition, not an ongoing, repeated performance. There might be several rounds of the show leading to a final (like the X Factor) but this is not the same as a run of performances of the same show or even a TV serial or a soap opera since, in those, everyone is working from the same script.

A talent show is most similar in format to a variety show since each act works independently of the others but, in a variety show, each performer basically repeats their act without a competitive element or a panel of judges.

In the case of variety shows, runs of plays, TV serials and soap operas each person is a *member of the cast* working, basically, to the common aim of making the show a success. For this reason we can say that someone has *joined* or *taken part in* a variety show but we can only say that they have *taken part in* a talent contest.

*Joined in* is even more restricted. It is not used for talent shows because the person is a competitor rather than a member of a team working to a common aim: also it is not used for professional commitments or even formal amateur organisations. It is used almost exclusively for informal amateur performances. One could say "Tom has joined in the community singing" for example but not even "Tom has joined in the community choir" because the choir is a more or less formal organisation with practice sessions (so one can either *join* it or *take part* in) it whereas community singing is something one does informally.

We can use "taken part in" for most of this type of activity but "joined" or "joined in" are not appropriate for competitions.